# How to show categories in each post

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to show my categories at each of my posts,

So far I have tried the following:

```
@if(isset($post->category->name_slug))
   {{ action('PagesController@showCategory', ['id' => $post->category
       >name_slug ]) }} {{ $post->category->name }}
@endif
```

but still no result, any idea?

Comment: do you have a `many to many` relationship between `post` and `category` or `many to one` ? and do you want to display post's category/ies when displaying the posts in a template ?

Comment: i have a "many to one" relationship, and while displaying the post, on the top of each post to be shown the category of that post. I don't know if i was clear. Thanks for the replay!

Comment: so it's even simpler, when you are looping through your posts you can print out the category of the post like `$post->category->name`

Answer (score 0):

In order to display all categories of your post you just need to loop through the categories of the post like so :

**I updated my code according to the change in your question**

```
// post here refers to the current post you are displaying 
// so this loop may be contained inside another loop that displays the posts

    {{ $post->category->name }}
```

from the code you posted above, I doubt that you named your relationship in the `Post` model correctly, because it should be `categories` and not `category`

Comment: sorry my mistake one post doesn't have more than one category, sorry

Answer (score 0):

In your `Post.php` model set up the relationship to a category

```
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo(App\Category::class);
}
```

In your `Category.php` model, set up the relationship to many posts

```
public function posts() {
   return $this->hasMany(App\Post::class);
}
```

Now, as long as your `posts` table has a `category_id` column, you can call on these relationships.

`Category: {{ $post->category->name }}`

And of course, if you want to, say, list all the posts in a certain category:

```
foreach($category->posts as $post) {
    // do something here
}
```

---

If a post can have many categories, you need to set up a pivot table.
`posts`, `category_post`, `categories`

On your `category_post` pivot table you have: `post_id`, `category_id`

This relationship is defined in your `Post.php` model like this:

```
public funtion categories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(App\Category::class, 'category_post');
}
```

And to call this, of course you use the relationship like this:

```
Categories:

foreach($post->categories as $category) {
   {{ $category->name }}
}
```

Comment: appreciate your help but i have done the above things, mine are postscontroller.php, categoryscontroller.php. now when i try to show it at my allposts.php, nothing happens.

Comment: Are you using Laravel correctly? Your question was: "I want to show my categories at each of my posts," - and I gave you the correct way to do it with Laravel. Seems like you're not fully understanding how Laravel works. If I'm mistaken, at least provide some more information in your post so we know how you are approaching things. I can only assume you are doing it the "laravel way", but if you are doing it another way, we need to know.